# Hikvision CAM resend logger

Tags: http, tcp, httpresponse

I am in possession of a Hickvison camera model, specifically the HIKVISION iDS-2CD7A46G0/-IZHS. In the event that a camera equipped with an SD card initiates a data transfer, it will resend previous logs.

I acknowledge receipt with a response status of HTTP/1.1 200 .

the manual suggests the user a space after 200 "HTTP/1.1 200", but not the solver.